# Internet explorer not rendering Google font

Tags: fonts

I have integrated Google API font into my site [Photoshop Download Free](http://www.photoshopdownloadfree.com) but the issue is that the font is not rendering correctly on **Internet Explorer** but seems perfect on **firefox** and **chrome**. Please let me know the solution of this issue. Please let me know the solution of this issue. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem some time ago. The thing is that every browser(render engine) uses a different font-file (some use .ttf, some .wotf and so forth). If the particular Google font you are using isn't provided in the format you need for IE (I believe it is .eos that is used by IE), you won't get the font to render. 
First of all try to change the font - if it works with another font it's probably the problem I've described above.
To make 100% sure that you have all the necessary files you could host them yourself. http://www.fontsquirrel.com/ has an excelent tool for generating self hosted fonts -> @font-face generator.

Good luck!